# Apriltags3, how can I improve pose ambiguity when a marker faces camera?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, fiducial-markers, apriltags

I have an c++ application that uses Apriltags3 fiducial markers.

These seem fast and stable, except in the case where the marker is facing flat to the camera, or thereabouts.

in these cases, the pose flips significantly, making the pose data unusable.
This flipping, as I understand it, is a known issue with square markers, as there are two possible solutions to estimate the pose.

How can i improve this flipping? 
I have tried:

1 - Using SolvePnp with the IPPE_SQUARE flag, i am able to return both solutions.

```
std::vector<cv::Vec3d> rvecsVec, tvecsVec;
std::vector<double> errs;
solvePnPGeneric(markerObjPoints, marker.corners2d, K, D, rvecsVec, tvecsVec, false, cv::SOLVEPNP_IPPE_SQUARE, cv::noArray(), cv::noArray(),errs);
```

then i choose the pose that is closest to the previous pose. this works well until the rotation of the pose passes zero (positive to negative values) and then the rotation axis flips.

2 - storing the previous few poses and running sliding window bundle adjustment on the 3d points, the 2d corners, and the poses.
This seems to have no effect, and I still see the same flipping.

3 - Using the following:

```
cv::Mat R1;
cv::Rodrigues(rvecsVec[0], R1);
R1 = R1.t();
cv::Mat t1 = -R1 * tvecsVec[0];

cv::Mat R2;
cv::Rodrigues(rvecsVec[1], R2);
R2 = R2.t();
cv::Mat t2 = -R2 * tvecsVec[1];
```

To get the camera poses relative to the markers. I would have assumed that a camera pose with a positive X value (in front of the marker) would be the correct one, however, when i use that pose:

```
if (t1.at<double>(0, 0) < 0)
    {
        marker.rvec = rvecsVec[0];
        marker.tvec = tvecsVec[0];
        std::cout << "using pose 0" << std::endl;

    }
    if (t2.at<double>(0, 0) < 0)
    {
        marker.rvec = rvecsVec[1];
        marker.tvec = tvecsVec[1];
        std::cout << "using pose 1" << std::endl;       
    }
```

I see the same issue as with solution 1.

4 - using a stereo camera, find the markers in each frame, triangulate the points and then use an Eigen SVD function to find the rigid transformation between these points and a set of points created from markerlength at zero.

```
PointsType p1s, p2s;
p1s.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(-markerLength / 2.f, markerLength / 2.f, 0));
p1s.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(markerLength / 2.f, markerLength / 2.f, 0));
p1s.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(markerLength / 2.f, -markerLength / 2.f, 0));
p1s.push_back(Eigen::Vector3d(-markerLength / 2.f, -markerLength / 2.f, 0));
```

This works great for translation, but rotation seems to flip even more!

IS there an answer for this? What else can I try?

Note: I have tested with Aruco markers, the same camera and calibration, and I do not see this flipping issue, it seems like a problem with Apriltags3.

Comment: Hello! I'm facing a similar issue, were you able to find a good solution to this issue? Also, for the first solution using Pnp, what is 'markerObjPoints', how do you obtain the markerObjPoints from Apriltag, since it gives only 2D pixel coordinate. Did you use that, and the length of square to convert it to 3D? Thanks

Comment: Hi @ShrutheeshRamanIyer, markerObjPoints is the 3d points of the marker. You can get these using markerSize and offsetting 4 points from zero. The ambiguity issue I solved in the end by switching to a different marker dictionary, 36h_11 is much more stable.

Comment: hi @anti thanks, I am using 36_h11, but it is still fairly unstable when the tag faces the camera. By using the markersize and offsetting 4 points from zero, that is still in 2D right? How would I set the 'z' (depth) value for the object points

Comment: Just use 0 for the z.